# Smplayer + MPV subtitle size

Tags: video, fonts, mplayer, subtitle, smplayer

I started using

> Smplayer 16.1.10 + MPV (git-9a2a0b0)

on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and i realized that i cannot set my subtitle font size by default.

I go to preferences and subtitle and i set it to different sizes but the size never changes in reality. Only if i manually chooe `Size+` or `Size-` it will change for the current movie/session i am using.

This was working well before when i used Mplayer and the default Smplayer version that comes with Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Comment: mpv is not mplayer & is used by smplayer in a slightly different way. I'd suggest you ask here - http://forum.smplayer.info/

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Be sure you have changed the **scale**.

[image]